# Teamviewer core dump on startup

Tags: 18.04, teamviewer

I've installed teamviewer on Ubuntu 18 following these instructions: https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/

[image]

but as you see it crashes, when I launch it. (I also tried running it as root, it doesn't like it). How can I fix this?

Comment: "core dumped" -> find the file, view the file, search the interesting parts online and/or add those into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you used the .deb Ubuntu packages... . When I've had problems with the official distro packages in the past, I have also downloaded the tar package from "Other systems (not officially supported)". These packages are stand-alone, and as such you run them by untar'ing and then executing the binary in the base of the extracted directory:

```
tar -xJf teamviewer_amd64.tar.xz
cd teamviewer
./teamviewer
```

The stand-alone version runs independently, and can help iron out issues with the official package, vs runtime issues.

Also, as per the Teamviewer support site, check debug logs via:

```
sudo teamviewer ziplog
```

In addition, since the process fails when trying to load the Teamviewer GUI, check for issues with libqt5gui5.